# How to optimally search dictionary database in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a word game and for that purpose I have a database table with about 20000 English words with lengths between 2 and 5 letters. The table structure is simple:

```
id | word  | length
1  | stuff | 5
2  | ask   | 3
```

So the word length has its own column, I'm not sure if that can be helpful but it's there for now.

The principle of the game involves the user typing 5 letters (dictated to him) and trying to complete as long a word as possible. For example, let's say he has the letters A, C, F, R, T. He has to type all 5. So he can put together the word `CRAFT`. Or, if he doesn't figure that one out, he can see the word `RAFT`. If he doesn't see that, maybe he'll see `ART`. But - he can't just type 3 or 4 letters in this case, he has to type all 5 (for reasons which are related to the rest of the game, and not relevant here). So it has to be something like `ARTFC` or `CFART`. Now, the question.

The app (PHP or Node.js) has to search the MySQL database for all words the user may have typed within the string. First it should search for 5 letter words, then if it doesn't find any it should search for 4 letter words (if the user typed `ARTFC` it should search for `ARTF` and `RTFC`) that may be present in the 5-character string. If it doesn't find that, 3 letter words etc.

This seems like it could be a bit slow. The user can submit up to 10 such 5-character strings simultaneously, and the number of users is difficult to predict. So, can anyone suggest a better way to perform this search than splitting the string up and sending consecutive queries until we find a word in it?

As a sub-question, do you think InnoDB would be a better choice of engine here than MyISAM? The only purpose of the DB table is this search, nothing has to be written to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with **MyISAM** mysql engine for read intensive tasks.
 As for table design to get a better performance you can create the word letters using partitions and SUBPARTITION .
 What do i mean by that:

- you will get max 26 letters - that means you will have 26 partitions
- each of this partition will have 4 SUBPARTITION

  - one for 2 letters words
  - one for 3 letters words
  - one for 4 letters words
  - one for 5 letters words

And after all this is done increase you query cache size see [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html) on how to